# Relatively simple SQL query to Linq (with grouping)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I have an sql statement that needs to be modified to any correct form of Linq (query syntax and/or lambda) -- any thoughts will be greatly appreciated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME, 
    COUNT(*) AS 'COUNT',
    SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'State1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'State1Count',
    SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'State2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'State2Count',
    ISNULL(SUM(USD_TOTAL_MRC_AMT), 0) AS 'USD_TOTAL_MRC_AMT_SUM'        
FROM Table1
WHERE
 (
    USERID = @UserId   //@UserId is a parameter passed into the stored procedure
)
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME
ORDER BY
    CUSTOMER_NAME
```

Here's along the lines what I have working so far in LinqPad:

```
Table1.GroupBy(i => 1).Select(g => new { 
Total = g.Count(i => i.State == "AM Re-Rate Pool" || i.State == "AM Renewal Pool"),
ReRates = g.Count(i => i.State == "State1"),
Renewals = g.Count(i => i.State == "State2
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: What part are you having issues with?

Comment: FYI It's called method syntax, not lambda.

Comment: haven't successfully added in the CUSTOMER_NUM & CUSTOMER_NAME in the groupings

Comment: result should look like this:

    CUSTOMER_NAME  CUSTOMER_NUMBER, TOTAL, State1, State2
            john doe                            3                          10        2           8
            jane doe                            4                          15        5          10

Comment: [SQL to LINQ conversion](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) || [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it with method syntax.

```
Table1.Where(t => t.UserId = userId)
      .OrderBy(t => t.CustomerName)
      .GroupBy(t => new {t.Customer_Num, t.Customer_Name})
      .Select(grp => new
      {
          grp.Key.Customer_Num,
          grp.Key.Customer_Name,
          Count = grp.Count(),
          State1Count = grp.Where(t => t.State = "State1").Count(),
          State2Count = grp.Where(t => t.State = "State2").Count(),
          USD_TOTAL_MRC_AMT_SUM = grp.Sum(t => t.USD_TOTAL_MRC_AMT_SUM) ?? 0
      })
      .Distinct();
```